# Запятая в сложносочиненном предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Чтобы уже раз и навсегда развязаться с подобными вопросами: нужно ли ставить запятую перед "и", если предложение самом по себе содержит два вопроса,начинающиеся с "какой", "каковы"?

Какое направление работы группы компаний в России сегодня вышло на первое место, и какой из регионов сегодня имеет наиболее емкий рынок по объему продаж?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Какое направление работы группы компаний в России сегодня вышло на первое место и какой из регионов сегодня имеет наиболее емкий рынок по объему продаж?

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

1) Кто вы такие и что вам надобно? Запятая не ставится при наличии одиночного соединительного союза И  и общей вопросительной интонации (отсутствие запятой говорит о том, что оба предложения являются вопросительными). В этом примере также два вопросительных местоимения.

2) Такие ССП следует отличать от варианта, когда вопросительным является только второе предложение (запятая ставится): Мы никогда не увидимся, и поэтому почему не сказать правду?